# Count number of digits in a String

Tags: apex

I'm trying to find a way to count number of digits in a string. 
I've tried the following code but it doesn't match any thing...

```
Pattern ptn = Pattern.compile('(\\d+)');
   Matcher m = ptn.matcher('854124');
   Integer cpt = 0;
   if(m.find()) {
     do{
      cpt++;  
     } 
     while(m.find());
   }
system.debug('number of digits: '+cpt);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like that.. I know there will a optimal solution

```
String str1 = '854124';
Integer cpt = 0;
for(String str : str1.split(''))
{
    Pattern ptn = Pattern.compile('\\d+');
    Matcher m = ptn.matcher(str);

   if(m.find()) {
      cpt++;  
   }
}

system.debug('number of digits: '+cpt);
```

Comment: No it still doesn't work

Comment: @JoeyPablo try above example in dev console.. You want to count the total length or just count the Integer in given string ?

Comment: @JoeyPablo Can you pls add some example what you are expecting ? if string is `'854124'` then it should give 6 or 1?

Comment: It should return 6. thank you for your answers :)